# Enums from imported maven libraries result in a compile error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have written my own library. However when importing it via maven the enums of that library are not implemented correctly.

[image]

When trying to use them it says cannot resolve symbol.
[image]

This is a IntelliJ issue only. When I generate the jar via `mvn clean compile assembly:single` the jar is been created and the program also works. I am using the newest Java version (Java 21) in all instances.

I appreciate your help! Thanks a lot

I tried both IJ COmmunity and IJ Ultimate edition. I also tried "invalidate caches" and "reimport maven".

Here is the pom:

```
<repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
</repository>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.Xahrie</groupId>
    <artifactId>trueapi</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.72</version>
</dependency>
```

Im currently using Version 2022.3.1.

Comment: How do you add the dependency? Can you share the corresponding part of the pom.xml? Also, try IDEA 2023.3, it has improved JDK 21 support.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: upgrading to IntelliJ 2023.3 solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upgrading to IntelliJ 2023.3 solved the issue

Comment: It would be useful if you tried to do some research, e.g. at the JetBrains issue tracking tool, and shared with us if this was a known bug which was fixed etc. Thus you will make your question and answer useful also for others. And if you then reformulate it so it is clear **what *exactly*** was in your project that made IntelliJ non-working.

Comment: I actually didnt know about it. Thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: Well, I don't know **if** that *was* a bug they fixed. I just believe it would be useful if you found and shared :)